# Sorting lists of edges in Python

Tags: python, sorting, graph

I am trying to sort a list of unique edges in Python, such that the sort has lists of the edges in order based on the preceding edge having a shared vertex with the next edge. I already have a function to get the "start" and "end" edges.

For example, an unsorted edge list would be this:

```
[[0, 5], [2, 4], [4, 5], [1, 2], [0, 6]]
```

Properly sorted, this would be as follows:

```
[[6, 0], [0, 5], [4, 5], [2, 4], [1, 2]]
```

with [6, 0] is the start edge and [1, 2] is the end edge.

Based on the sort methods I have seen, the sort is done based on knowing which index in the list you want to sort by, but in this case, the index could be either 0 or 1.

Comment: What is the expected output if the input is `[[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]`?

Comment: @ColinBasnett If I understand correctly, the start and end of the list are pre specified, and the middle of the list is the route of the edges one must take to get from the start to the end

Comment: Basically what you are doing is not sorting. It is a kind of path finding. Sorting is done by asserting the order of two item several times. When you you can't determine the order of two items without having a look at other items then it's no sort.

Comment: @KlausD. is correct, this is not sorting, it's path-finding. I think we need to know a little bit more about the expected outputs for odd inputs. What about an input set like: `[[0,1],[1,2],[9,10]]`. Is `[9,10]` wanted in the output list, even though it's disjointed? What about `[[0,1],[0,2],[0,3]]`?

Comment: @Kevin I've already set it so that there are no ambiguous paths based on the edge vertices setting out a curve that has a unique identifier. The case you gave would not happen. At most, a vertex appears twice in the edges. The start and end vertices appear only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

followed_by = defaultdict(list)

def follows(edge1, edge2):  # does edge2 follow edge1
    return edge1 != edge2 and not set(edge1).isdisjoint(set(edge2))

def sorted_path(path, end):

    start = path[-1]

    for follower in followed_by[tuple(start)]:

        if follower in path:
            continue  # avoid circularities

        if follower == end:
            return path + [end]  # solution found

        new_path = sorted_path(path + [follower], end)  # recurse

        if new_path:
            return new_path  # solution found

    return None  # solution not found

# build defaultdict of who follows who

for edge in edges:
    for potential_follower in edges:
        if follows(edge, potential_follower):
            followed_by[tuple(edge)].append(potential_follower)

edges = [[0, 5], [2, 4], [4, 5], [1, 2], [0, 6]]

START = [0, 6]

END = [1, 2]

print(sorted_path([START], END))  # pass the path so far and terminal node
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a few assumptions about the input:

1. The start node and end node appear in the list only once.
2. Every node that isn't the start node and end node appear twice.
3. The path is fully defined (there are no disjoint points).

Given these assumptions, the first thing I would do is to turn the inputs into frozenset<sup>1</sup> to be able to take advantage of hashing:

```
edges = [frozenset(edge) for edge in edges]
```

Now I'd construct a mapping from nodes to edges:

```
from collections import defaultdict
nodes_to_edges = defaultdict(set)
for edge in edges:
    for node in edge: 
        nodes_to_edges[node].add(edge)
nodes_to_edges.default_factory = None
```

And now, the path is defined by traversing `nodes_to_edges`.  Here I'll set the start node by hand since you know it.  If you don't know the start node, you can find a key in `nodes_to_edges` whose contained set has a length of one.  There will be 2 such keys (the start node and end node), but if the graph is undirected, then you can traverse either way and it makes no difference:

```
current_node = 6
path = []
while nodes_to_edges:
    edge = nodes_to_edges[current_node].pop()
    assert not nodes_to_edges[current_node]
    del nodes_to_edges[current_node]
    path.append(edge)

    next_node = next(iter(edge - {current_node}))
    next_edges = nodes_to_edges[next_node]
    if len(next_edges) == 1:  # End node.
        del nodes_to_edges[next_node]
    else:
        next_edges.remove(edge)
    current_node = next_node
```

A few invariants to keep in mind when you think about this implementation:

- Each edge exists in `nodes_to_edges` twice.  So for every edge that we add to the `path`, we need to remove two from `nodes_to_edges`.
- We could get rid of my third assumption above *iff* you know the start node by adding a `break` statement to the `else` clause.  I think this probably also relaxes the second assumption a bit as well -- the new assumption would be that no node has more than 2 edges connected to it.

<sup><sup>1</sup>I used a frozenset because it looks like you are using undirected edges.  If the edges are directed, you'd need to modify thisto use a tuple.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The following code is not an efficient approach, but completes your example. Hypothesis of unique solution is taken understanding "unique edges" in that sense.

```
lst = [[0, 5], [2, 4], [4, 5], [1, 2], [0, 6]]
l=len(lst)
#Your function gives ini and end:
ini = [0, 6]
end = [1, 2]
sol = [ini]
lst.remove(ini)
lst.remove(end)
while len(sol) < l - 1:
    for x in lst:
        if any(y in x for y in sol[-1]):
            sol.append(x)
            lst.remove(sol[-1])
            break
sol.append(end)
print("sol", sol)
```